# routing based on parameter value in camel context file

Tags: apache-camel

Hi I have a route which is

```
<route id="invokeGetMortgageAccountDetails">
<from uri="direct:invokeGetMortgageAccountDetails" />
<removeHeaders pattern="operationNamespace" />
<setHeader headerName="operationName">
<constant>getMortgageDetailsRequest</constant>
</setHeader>            
<to uri="cxf:bean:getBastionAcctDetailsClient" />                   
<removeHeaders pattern="*" />
</route>
```

Now i want to change the 'to uri' if length of parameter account is equal to 8.

I am new to Apache camel and there is not very helpful information on internet.

I am using camel version 2.15 and i tried passing an extra property called length of account number in exchange and tried to match with value in route but it did not work.

Processor:

> public void processMortgage(final Exchange exchange) throws
>   ServiceException {        MessageContentsList messageContentsList =
>   (MessageContentsList) exchange.getIn().getBody();         List
>   paramsList = new ArrayList();         String systemID =
>   messageContentsList.get(0).toString().trim();         String brandID =
>   messageContentsList.get(1).toString().trim();         String account =
>   messageContentsList.get(2).toString().trim();         String len =
>   Integer.toString(account.length());               paramsList.add(Constants.HUB);
>             paramsList.add(brandID.toUpperCase());          paramsList.add(account);
>             exchange.setProperty(Constants.SystemID, systemID);
>             exchange.setProperty(len, len);
>             exchange.setProperty(Constants.ErrorCode, null);
>             exchange.setProperty("mortgageAccountNumber",
>   Integer.parseInt(account));                               }
>         exchange.getIn().setBody(paramsList);           }

Route Config:

```
<route id="invokeGetMortgageAccountDetails">             
<from uri="direct:invokeGetMortgageAccountDetails" />           <removeHeaders pattern="operationNamespace" />           
<setHeader headerName="operationName">
<constant>getMortgageDetailsRequest</constant>           </setHeader>            <choice>
                <when>
                    <simple>${body.len} == '8'</simple>
                    <to uri="cxf:bean:getPhoebusClient" />
                </when>
                <otherwise>
                    <to uri="cxf:bean:getBastionAcctDetailsClient" />
                </otherwise>            
 </choice>              
   <removeHeaders pattern="*" />         
 </route>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apache Camel version > 2.16 then you can use the

[Dynamic To Endpoint](http://camel.apache.org/spel.html)

You will probably need to use [Spring Expression Language](http://camel.apache.org/spel.html) to build your dynamic uri